# Wordpress Custom Post Type Frontend Timestamps

Tags: wordpress, timestamp, custom-post-type

I know that Stackoverflow is normally for coding assistance, but I have a quick question for the community - if this could be better answered in another forum, I apologise, and if you could let me know where to ask, I will do so:

Question: When creating a new post on the front end via a custom post type, does wordpress automatically create the relevant timestamps? If it does, does that mean that it would automatically modify the timestamps or create the last modified values or do I need to add hidden fields in the form(s) to do so?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [get_the_modified_date](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_modified_date) and [get_the_modified_time](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_modified_time) functions.

You should be able to execute these either in The Loop or in a Custom Post type page itself.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into those functions. So you're indicating that time/date IS automatically saved with posts?